# Input parameters in Dirichlet density function

Tags: r, density-function, dirichlet-distribution

I'm trying to feed the [Dirichlet density function](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DirichletReg/index.html) with some sample data and estimated alpha vector using R in Python (library rpy2), but I don't understand the error that I got:

```
>>> q['dirichlet2b'] = DirichletReg.ddirichlet(np.asarray(mySample),np.asarray(listOfAlphas), log=False, sum_up=True)
Error in rowSums(alpha) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 82, in __call__
    return super(SignatureTranslatedFunction, self).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpy2/robjects/functions.py", line 34, in __call__
    res = super(Function, self).__call__(*new_args, **new_kwargs)
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in rowSums(alpha) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
```

The function I'm dealing with is declared as:
`ddirichlet(x, alpha, log = FALSE, sum.up = FALSE)` .
Its implementation is [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/%2acheckout%2a/pkg/R/dirichlet_misc.R?root=dirichletreg).

From the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DirichletReg/DirichletReg.pdf):

> alpha the Dirichlet distribution’s parameters. Can be a vector (one
>   set of parameters
>         for all observations) or a matrix (a different set of parameters for each observa-
>        tion), see details
>   Details:

```
Usually, alpha is a vector thus the same parameters will be used for all observations. If alpha is a
matrix, a complete set of alpha-parameters must be supplied for each observation.
```

So 
In a test I am running, these are the values of the two variables:

```
>>> mySample
[0.23947368421052631, 0.29122807017543861, 0.13596491228070176, 0.24473684210526317]
>>> listOfAlphas
[0.96321625726816873, 0.010664397021223898, 0.0073408705340313662, 0.011574312890446362]
```

Why should I need a matrix of alphas for my observations? What exactly is needed to feed a Dirichlet density function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error appears to be caused by the fact that `x` is not a matrix.  The reason why `x` needs to be a matrix, in principle is that the Dirichlet is a multivariate distribution; each of your $N$ observations has, let us say, $K$ elements, leading naturally to a representation of `x` as an $N \times K$ matrix.  Even if you only have one observation, the function as implemented in `DirichletReg` is looking for a $1 \times K$ matrix (but see below for an alternative.)  Here's the relevant line of code from the implementation:

```
  if(is.null(dim(x))) stop("x must be a matrix")
```

`alpha` does not need to be a matrix; however, if it is a matrix, it needs to be $N \times K$ as well.  The latter representation allows for a Dirichlet with each observation having a different parameterization.

Try constructing `x` as a matrix and see if that fixes the problem.

The example below uses the `ddirichlet` function in the `gtools` package, which has the same calling structure as that in `DirichletReg` (for some directory-related reason I can't get `DirichletReg` to load in python, but I can get `gtools` to load):

```
>>> xval = robjects.FloatVector([0.3,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.3,0.2])
>>> x = robjects.r['matrix'](xval, nrow=2)
>>> alpha = robjects.FloatVector([4,4,2])
>>> print(x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  0.3  0.4  0.3
[2,]  0.5  0.3  0.2

>>> print(alpha)
[1] 4 4 2

>>> gtools.ddirichlet(x,alpha)
<FloatVector - Python:0x3e5e830 / R:0x2ec7748>
[5.225472, 6.804000]
```

Also note that `gtools`'s implementation of `ddirichlet` treats `x` differently than `DirichletReg`'s implementation of `ddirichlet`:

```
if (!is.matrix(x)) 
    if (is.data.frame(x)) 
        x <- as.matrix(x)
    else x <- t(x)
```

It looks like you can just load a vector in, as you wished, and it will be converted to a row vector.  Let's try it:

```
>>> x2 = robjects.FloatVector([0.3,0.4,0.3])
>>> alpha = robjects.FloatVector([3,4,3])
>>> gtools.ddirichlet(x2,alpha)
<FloatVector - Python:0x2c63a28 / R:0x266ee58>
[7.838208]
```

So that's another fix to your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I'm now comparing the results yielded by [this implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658866/calculating-pdf-of-dirichlet-distribution-in-python) and those given by the implementation in gtool.  They usually match, but sometimes a few strange things happen.
case 1) I get values slightly > 1  (like 1.07) when there is only one x and one alpha. Why should a density function return such a value?

Comment: case 2) x = [0.99401197604790414, 0.0059880239520958087]
 alphas =[0.16590711348505713, 0.029765153762857845]
 ======> implementation 1:  3.66328469334 ; implementation 2:  3.663285

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFO FOR CASE 1)
 x=[0.94736842105263153]; alphas = [0.032034681077891182]======> implementation 1: 1.05372888806 ; implementation 2: 0.   This happens very often when I have only 1 value and 1 alpha. Does it make sense? Also, why do the two densities differ?